# How to get attribute from actionlink

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

How can I get attributes from an ActionLink? I have this:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Chat", "Home", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "Group" })<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

On the redirect page I need to get `item.name`

Here's my JS:

```
$('#rooms ul li').not('.nav-header').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#rooms ul li').not('.nav-header').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    var roomKey = $(this).data('value');
    hub.server.joinGroup(roomKey);
});
```

Comment: Is it showing `href` attribute in DOM when you do inspect element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can attr() event

```
$(selector).attr('/form or id or class any on of attribute/');
```

Comment: Thanks for solution, is it will be good for getting name? 'var roomKey = $(selector).attr('item.Name');'